# PHP Form Validation - foreach

Tags: php, validation, foreach

All the submitted fields are available in $_POST array. So we can iterate over this array to check if the value of required fields are exist or not.The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$post = $_POST;
if(count($post) > 0) {

    foreach($post as $key => $value) {

        if(empty($post[$key])) {
        $message =  $key . " is required!";
        break;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

**I want to this action:**

For example when the username field is empty the message is printed input1 is required!. input1 is same the name of the username field.

I want to echo username is required but without changing name of the username field.

For example, a code like the following, but does not work and I do not know where and how!

```
if($key == 'input1'){
    $key = 'username';
}
else
if($key == 'input2'){
    $key = 'password';
}
```

Form and inputs elements in the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.tableheader {
    background-color: #CCC;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.tablerow {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    color: #333;
}
.message {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10;
}

</style>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<div align="center" class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) echo $message; ?></div>
<form name="registrationform" method="post" action="" style="direction: ltr">

<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" width="500" align="center">
<tr class="tableheader">
<td align="center" colspan="2">Registration Form</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablerow">
<td align="right">Username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="input1" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['input1'])) echo $_POST['input1']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="tablerow">
<td align="right">Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="input2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['input2'])) echo $_POST['input2']; ?>"></td>
</tr>


<tr class="tableheader">
<td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you are asking. Can you be a bit clearer?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer
For example when the username field is empty the message is printed input1 is required!. input1 is same the name of the username field.

I want to echo username is required but without changing name of the username field.

Comment: You have to use a `switch` statement or find a way to map the actual names you want to display, e.g username to the form names, e.g input1

Comment: What output do you get now. Does the form gets submitted without validating the required fields ?

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer: Thank you. But how do I use switch? Can you give an example?

Comment: Added an example of using a map of the field names to the actual display names

Comment: What happens if someone submits a post request to your script and doesn't include one of the fields you're checking for? You have no check for this. For example, I could send a request without 'input1' at all (not just empty) and your check would not notice.

Answer (score 6):

If understood correctly... you need another array where you'd keep a "map" of your input fields' names and their actual "human" names. Something like:

```
$fields_map = array(
  'input1' => 'Username',
  'input2' => 'Password',
  'whatever' => 'something'
)
```

..then, when you want to output the message to user, then you'd do something like:

```
if(empty($post[$key])) {
   $message =  $fields_map[$key] . " is required!";
}
```

Comment: That! That is beauty :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```php
<?php
$post = $_POST;
$message='';
if(count($post) > 0) {

    foreach($post as $key => $value) {

        if(empty($post[$key])) {
        $message .=  $key . " is required!";
        break;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `switch` statement or find a way to map the actual names you want to display, e.g username to the form names, e.g input1.

An example of such mapping is presented below:

```
$map = array('input1'=>'username', 'input2'=>'surname', 'input3'=>'othernames');
$post = $_POST;
if(count($post) > 0) {

   foreach($post as $key => $value) {

      if(empty($post[$key])) {
         $message =  $map[$key] . " is required!";
         break;
      }
   }
}
```